# Compress file with HTML, JavaScript (or JQUERY), CSS and PHP

Tags: compression

I´m thinking in compress the pages of my site. The regular ones with HTML, JavaScript (or Jquery), CSS and PHP. I´m not talking about the *.css or *.js files, if not, the rest.

**Which is the best method, soft, way (etc) to do it without generating conflicts with the code?**

All these files have parts of codes of the previous languages: the general structure of html (tags and DIV for layout), some internal CSS (style and inline), several JavaScript call (to other *.js files and some functions like show, hide, toogle, onclick, etc) and PHP.

I tried to merge all the lines with my Notepad++ but it gave me a lot of errors, so I decided to go back.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you talking about, say, gzip compression, or are you speaking strictly of concatenation and minification?

Comment: I think what you are describing is called "minimizing"... Compression is usually used in reference to gzipping your content at the server level. Both are recommended, but I'd argue that the gzip compression is more important than minimization.  What type of web server are you using?

Comment: @scunliffe I´m thinking in what can be better! hahaha. Honestly, I´m reading about YUI and several minimizers, but I want to convert all my files, not just *.css or *.js, if not, also, those who have several code and languages. I´m using APACHE with the service of HOSTGATOR. And I put this, because I do not know HOW much I can configure under a shared hosting account. Thanks :D